# Rendering issue with removeChild() function on Opera

Tags: javascript, opera, removechild

I encountered a problem with removeChild() function on Opera 12.15.

```
var lines = document.getElementById('lines');
while(lines.hasChildNodes()) lines.removeChild(lines.firstChild);
```

Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7ZmW/

The red text remains visible after the nodes have been deleted.

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: Please **explain** what's happening in **Opera**. I can only test in Firefox/Chrome, so I can't see what the problem is...

Comment: If it *helps*, you could try using `lines.removeChild(lines.childNodes[0]);` instead, maybe

Comment: It might save intermediate redraws and perhaps avoid the problem if you just did `lines.innerHTML = "";`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but neither of them did solve the problem, weird.

Comment: Looks like a rendering issue in Opera. Doesn't matter what you use, the text still stays, but if you inpect the DOM, the elements are actually gone, it just looks like it's not properly redrawed on the screen? Seems jQuery does something to solve this issue when using remove(), so look at the source for that !

Comment: @adeneo which version of jQuery? I tested 1.9.1 and it has the same issue.

Comment: Was testing with 1.9 as well, and tried some more, and seems it works sometimes, sometimes some of the text dissapears and then the rest flickers and dissapears as well, and other times it doesn't work at all, so jQuery probably didn't solve this, it was a fluke that it worked the first time I tried it !